# Divide complex numbers in rectangular form

Tags: complex-numbers

I have attempted this complex number below. Is it correct?

$$\frac {4 + i1} {2 + i3} $$

This is what i have:

$$ \frac {4 + i1} {2 + i3} \times \frac {2 + i3} {2 + i3} $$

$$ \frac {8-12i +2 -3i^2} {4 -6i + 6 - 9i^2} $$

$$ \frac {8 -12i +2 -3i^2 (-1)} {4 - 6i + 6 -9i^2}$$

$$ \frac {8 -12i +2 + 31)} {4 - 6i + 6 + 9}$$

$$ \frac {39 - 10i} {13} $$

Is this correct??

Comment: What is the $x$ in the second formula?

Comment: When I square $2+3i$ I get $-5+12i$.

Comment: You can check yourself if it is correct by cross-multiplying (or by using e.g. WolframAlpha), btw.

Comment: You didn't square your denominator correctly (it would give $+6i$ twice rather than one $+$ and one $-$), but the idea that you need to get rid of the imaginary stuff on the bottom is correct. This is done by multiplying top and bottom by the complex conjugate, $2-3i$ however, rather than by squaring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and that is not the simplest approach. You can do it as follows:\begin{align}\frac{4+i}{2+3i}&=\frac{(4+i)(2-3i)}{(2+3i)(2-3i)}\\&=\frac{11-10i}{13}\\&=\frac{11}{13}-\frac{10}{13}i.\end{align}

Comment: Where did i go wrong?. Been stuck on this for ages.

Comment: $(4+2i)\times(2+3i)=8+4i+12i+6i^2\neq8-12i+2-3i^2$

Comment: @KyleAnderson You didn't square your denominator correctly (it would give $+6i$ twice rather than one $+$ and one $-$), but the idea that you need to get rid of the imaginary stuff on the bottom is correct. This is done by multiplying top and bottom by the complex conjugate, $2-3i$ however, rather than by squaring

Comment: Yes i understand now where i went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No. Use the ***opposite*** sign for the **imaginary part** in the denominator:

$$\frac {4 + 1i} {2 + 3i} = \frac {4 + 1i} {2 + 3i}\cdot \frac {2 - 3i} {2 - 3i}$$

to may use - in the denominator - the formula
$$ (A+iB).(A-iB) = A^2 + B^2$$

and obtain (still in the denominator) a **real** number.